# Regular expression for na_values using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nan

I want to read a file like this using `pandas.read_csv`

```
1891, 91920,  7,       628,249, 59,51.0, 0.026, 0.028,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,  0.156, 0.071,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,   21,500,   21,43.8, 0.005, 0.619,  NaN,45.6, 0.048, 0.053,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN, -0.180, 0.088,   20, 0.012, 1.107,  NaN, NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,  NaN,   NaN,   NaN,  NaN,     NaN,     NaN,     NaN
1891, 91920, 16,       628,135, 22,41.2, 0.093, 0.087,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,  0.416, 0.212,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,   21,500,   20,23.3, 0.021, 2.023,  NaN, NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,  NaN,   NaN,   NaN,  NaN, NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,  NaN,   NaN,   NaN,  NaN,     NaN,     NaN,     NaN
1891, 91920,  3,       628, 28, 39,47.0, 0.041, 0.044,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN, -0.006, 0.064,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,   21,500,   21,37.5, 0.009, 0.964,  NaN,45.3, 0.054, 0.055,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN, -0.838, 0.228,   20, 0.013, 1.193,  NaN,51.8, 0.025, 0.026,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN, -0.021, 0.054,   21, 0.005, 0.540,  NaN,     NaN,     NaN,     NaN
1891, 91920,  6,       628,276, 20,40.0, 0.118, 0.101,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN, -0.767, 0.558,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,    NaN,   NaN,   21,500,   20,26.7, 0.032, 2.982,  NaN,41.0, 0.088, 0.089,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN, -0.141, 0.233,   20, 0.024, 2.074,  NaN,46.2, 0.053, 0.049,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,   NaN,  0.080, 0.034,   21, 0.012, 1.187,  NaN,     NaN,     NaN,     NaN
```

I have a problem trying to read it because NaN values. If the file was a csv file (coma separated) I have no problem, but it have spaces. When I read it using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None, header=None)
```

Obviously the columns with NaN are read as strings because the spaces. My problem was easy if the spaces had the same dimension. I could use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None, header=None, na_values = "   NaN")
```

and problem solved, but there are columns with different blank spaces. Some of them have 4 spaces before the NaN, anothers 6 and so on.

So, my question is: Is there an regular expression for specify the `na_values` something like `na_values = "\s+ NaN"`?

Comment: Why not use a regex *separator*, like `sep=",\s+"`?

Comment: Alternatively you can use `delim_whitespace=True` or `skipinitialspace=True` parameter

Comment: @BrenBam skipinitialspace=True works fine, thanks. But sep=",\s+" doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(engine='python', index_col=None, sep=',\s*', header=None)
```

The parsing engine is set to `python` to avoid a warning you get when you use regex as a separator.